# Crear endPoint para traer los datos del usuario como nombre, el día que se registro, numero de publicaciones, etc ¿como lo hago?

Tags: crud, backend

Tengo un código para la creación y registro de usuarios y necestio un EndPoint para traer los datos del usuario como nombre, el día que se registro, numero de publicaciones que ha realizado, las publicaciones que ha creado, las reviews que le han dejado los demás usuarios, y si el usuario esta verificado o no
además No se necesita estar logueado para acceder al endpoint

ESTE ES EL USER CONTROLLER

```
@Controller('users')
export class UsersController {

    constructor(private readonly usersService: UsersService) {}

    @Post()
    async create(@Body() createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<IUser> {

         return await this.usersService.create(createUserDto);
    }

    @Get('profile/:user')
    async getProfile (@Res() res) {
        const profile = await this.usersService.getProfile();
        return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json({
            profile
        })
    }
}
```

ESTE ES EL USER SERVICE

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {

    constructor( @InjectModel('users') private readonly userModel: Model<IUser> ) {}

    async findOne(username: string): Promise<IUser> {

        return await this.userModel.findOne({ username });
    }

    async create(createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise <IUser> {

        const { username, password } = createUserDto

        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();

        const userExists = await this.findOne(username);
        if( userExists ) {
            throw new ConflictException('username already exists')
        }

        const user = new this.userModel(createUserDto);
        user.username = username;
        user.password = await this.hasPassword(password, salt);
        return await user.save();
    }
    private hasPassword(password, salt): Promise<string> {
        return bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
    }

    async getProfile(): Promise <IUser[]> {
        const profile = await this.userModel.find();
        return profile;
    }


}
```

este es el codigo que tengo ahora no se como crear ese endpoint

Comment: gracias pero necesito ayuda rapido

Comment: porfa una ayuda no he logrado hacerlo almenos un idea de como hacerlo

Comment: solamente necesito el endpoint

Comment: enserio nadie me va ayudar

Comment: si quieren les doy buenos puntos y demas para que sean los mejores a cambio de que me ayude